# openFileDialog.Title

Tags: c#

OpenFileDialog.Title file is not defined in my visual studio2008, so I am not able to open a file for a smartdevice application. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Please tell us what the question is

Comment: Are you using Compact Framework? If so, then the `OpenFileDialog` class is not available.

Comment: @0xA3: I have the OpenFileDialog in my visual studio under Device Dialogs in my toolbox, and according to msdn it's included as of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(VS.90).aspx (search for compact).

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, but seems the `Title` property is not included in the Compact Framework.

Comment: @0xA3: true, but there is a big difference between "`OpenFileDialog` class" and "`OpenFileDialog.Title` *property* ". ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the Title of the dialog to open a file with a `OpenFileDialog` on a SmartDevice. If you add a button and handle its Click event for instance, you can add some code similar to this to get a filename from a OpenFileDialog

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```